# How to update a field with a count of rows from another table on postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

So I used to simply just write something like

```
update tableA a
set columnA = (select sum(column_that_I_need_to_count) from tableB b where st_contains(a.geom, b.geom)
```

But for some reason updating like this does not work on my new database. It just runs the update indefinitely and never finishes

Now I have to write it as

```
 update tableA a
 set columnA = count(column_that_I_need_to_count) 
 from tableB b where st_contains(b.geom, a.geom)
```

Problem is that it says it doesn't allow count on an update

Create table statements are:

```
create tableA (
id integer,
name text,
geom geometry(polygon, 27700) 
)

create tableB(
fid bigint,
column_that_I_need_to_count integer,
name text,
geom geometry(point, 27700)
)
```

Is there a reason why different postgresql have different subquery rules for updating?

Also how to do the actual update? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you put your real query with an example with data? The first query is **OK**, It should work. The second query is **WRONG**, you can't use `count(*)` like that. There are many ways to do that kind of update. But since the first query is not working, maybe there is a problem with your database structure or your data.

Comment: @Dan The first query was how I was doing all my updates for the past year but now it just doesn't work on this new database, it runs it but never finishes. The second one doesn't work like you said, I just want to know how to work on this new database

Comment: If it runs and never finishes, most likely there is a problem with your database. Anyhow, I answered according to your information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a problem with your database. Like I said your first query doesn't seem to have a problem. I could conclude that the problem is not the query.

Perhaps the WAL (write ahead login) is too big and you need to restart your postgreSQL server **service** (not just restarting the server but the service as well).

Perhaps you need to work in some indexing for your tables.

You can run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to see what could be going wrong.

```
BEGIN;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE UPDATE tableA a set columnA = (SELECT SUM(column_that_I_need_to_count) FROM tableB b WHERE st_contains(a.geom, b.geom)
ROLLBACK;
```

`BEGIN` and `ROLLBACK` is for it to revert the changes and just see whats going on.

Since you say your query never ends, you should let it run like for an hour or two and see what the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` says, if it keeps running... well.. there is defenetly something wrong with your database.

Aside from that, your `SUM` might need a `GROUP BY`, 'cause if not, it will set the same value to all the rows.

For your second attempt. The correct way to do it is:

```
WITH counted AS(
  SELECT a.id as id_counted,SUM(b.column_that_I_need_to_count) AS counted_rows
  FROM tableA a, tableB b
  WHERE st_contains(a.geom, b.geom) GROUP BY a.id
)UPDATE tableA
SET columnA = counted_rows
FROM counted
WHERE id = id_counted;
```

Lastly, like @Emilio Platzer says, if you need to count, instead of `SUM` you should use `COUNT`... but perhaps you need a `SUM`... don't know.

Comment: I'll try a 'with' like you just gave me, otherwise I'll have to check with the sys admin.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
update tableA a
  set columnA = (select count(*) from tableB b where st_contains(b.geom, a.geom))
```

I do not test it. If you post a sample (with the create tables sentence and the inserts we can help you better).

Comment: Umm did you just copy paste my query or even read my first question? but sure I will add create table statements